# Eclipse removes import in use

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Galileo and I have a small problem.

Inside one of my classes (lets call it `Foo`)I have an import of an enum `DBAction` in another package `DB`.

With the import already specified in the code, it works fine, but whenever I press `Shift+Ctrl+O` (Organize imports) it removes that import, thus breaking my code.

Here is some of the code (with placeholder names):

```
package foo.bar.baz;

import foo.bar.DB.DBAction;
// Other imports.

// Constructor

// I use the DBAction (enum) here
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnAddEvent)
        new EventDialog(DBAction.INSERT);
}
```

This is Android, but I think it's not an Android specific problem.

Are there any ways to fix this bug?

Comment: Can you show the full src file, or is the data contained within too sensitive?

Comment: It's a bit sensitive, but I can surely post some of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when the class/package referenced in the import is not available on the classpath of the project.

Comment: Thanks! I restarted Eclipse and it got fixed (along with some other *bugs*).